# How to get video window from call on caller side in iOS?

Tags: ios, video, pjsip

[image]I am trying to make video calling functional with pjsip. I am using vialerSipLib demo app for this.

Here is the scenario i am trying.

Calling from phoneA to phoneB. Audio is working for both incoming and outgoing calls. But the problem is, video is working on phoneB(ReceiverSide) but I'm unable to get the video on phoneA(CallerSide). Here is my account configuration for video call.

I am using codec H264 for video calling.

```
acc_cfg.vid_in_auto_show = PJ_TRUE;
acc_cfg.vid_out_auto_transmit = PJ_TRUE;

acc_cfg.vid_wnd_flags = PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_BORDER | PJMEDIA_VID_DEV_WND_RESIZABLE;
acc_cfg.vid_cap_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_CAPTURE_DEV;
acc_cfg.vid_rend_dev = PJMEDIA_VID_DEFAULT_RENDER_DEV;
acc_cfg.reg_retry_interval = 300;
acc_cfg.reg_first_retry_interval = 30;
```

Here is how i am getting the video window using callid. There is a black window appeared. Or is there any way to check if the ci.media array has valid video?

```
- (void) displayWindowWithVoid: (UIView *) parent call:(VSLCall *)call {

int vid_idx;
pjsua_vid_win_id wid;

vid_idx = pjsua_call_get_vid_stream_idx((int)call.callId);
if (vid_idx >= 0) {
    pjsua_call_info ci;

    pjsua_call_get_info((int)call.callId, &ci);
    wid = ci.media[vid_idx].stream.vid.win_in;

    ci.setting.vid_cnt = 1;

    pjsua_vid_win_info wi;
    if (pjsua_vid_win_get_info(wid, &wi) == PJ_SUCCESS) {

        pjsua_vid_win_set_show(wid, true);
        UIView *view = (__bridge UIView *)wi.hwnd.info.ios.window;
         [parent addSubview:view];
    }
}   }
```

If any one can tell me a client for video calling so i can test the behaviour. Either its the issue on app side or server side. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Posting this answer as this might be helpful for any other and can save much of his time.

You must be changing your video formats

```
pjmedia_vid_codec_param param;
pjsua_vid_codec_get_param(&videoCodecInfo[i].codec_id, &param);
param.ignore_fmtp = PJ_TRUE;

param.enc_fmt.det.vid.size.w = 1280;
param.enc_fmt.det.vid.size.h = 720;
param.enc_fmt.det.vid.fps.num = 30;
param.enc_fmt.det.vid.fps.denum = 1;
param.dec_fmt.det.vid.size.w = 1280;
param.dec_fmt.det.vid.size.h = 720;
```

Might be what exactly format your server support may be helping you. 
If you need any more help. Please let me know

Comment: Hi @Ali Asad, I'm woking with video call, I had a problem when make call, when another accepted invitation, many another inventation was sent and I could not stop them. I don't know why?

Comment: On which side(caller or Receiver) you got invitation? and which type of signal do you receive? Is it media_change or any other? Because this might be due to adding observers multiple times  on a single view controller OR you are not removing the observer. 
Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for anwser my question, In Receiver, I got invitation like "RX 2025 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=7129 (rdata0x109af4348)". And in media_change, I START_TRANSMIT. It work fine but i can't hidden vid_preview.